# Edit the Timer Function once it has started

Tags: matlab, timer

I'm trying to figure out how to have a timer add time once it has begun. The idea is if a person clicks certain buttons in a GUI the timer increases by a given amount of time that is determined by a different variable. When I couldn't figure that out, I decided to just make a second timer that starts on a button click but the second timer won't display even though the code is the exact same so now I'm really at a loss.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iphzs.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgsMZ.png)

Comment: Please, avoid linking screenshots of code. Copy the code, paste it in the question **and format it as code** (after pasting it in the question, select it and click the button `{}` in the editor).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no way to adjust a running timer. I would recommend trying to use `tic`/`toc`. Put your time limit in some variable (`tLimit`), get the start time with `tic`, and then compute the elapsed time with `toc` and compare to `tLimit`.

```
tLimit = <some number>;
tStart = tic;
```

Then later in the code you check how much time has elapsed:

```
if toc(tStart) > tLimit
    % done
end
```

If you need to add time:

```
tLimit = tLimit + tExtra
```

If you really want to run your check in a timer object, you could create a function which does the time comparison, and have your timer run that:

```
function timeCheck(timerObj,~)
    global tStart
    global tLimit
    if toc(tStart) > tLimit
        fprintf('Time''s up! %0.1f seconds elapsed\n', toc(tStart));
        stop(timerObj);
    end
end
```

Then:

```
global tStart
global tLimit    
tLimit = <some number>;
t = timer;
t.TimerFcn = @timeCheck;
t.ExecutionMode = 'fixedRate';
tStart = tic;
start(t);
```